# Including \n in a string in python

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, sys

How do i escape \n in a string in python.

How do i write out to stdin in python this string `"abc\ndef"` as one single input

```
Sys.stdout.write("abc\ndef")
```

**current output**

```
import sys

>>> sys.stdout.write("abc\ndef")
abc
def
```

I would like it to be `abc\ndef`

Comment: try to escape the backslash `\\n`

Comment: @m02ph3u5, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer :-)

Comment: @Kevin this is so obvious answer it doesn't even feel like an answer :)

Comment: made it an answer anyhow :D

Comment: See also the docs on string literals, which includes a table of these backslash-escape sequences: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Answer (score 10):

You should escape the backslash so that it's not treated as escaping character itself:

```py
Sys.stdout.write("abc\\ndef")
```

**Background**

The backslash `\` tells the parser that the next character is something special and must be treated differently. That's why `\n` will not print as `\n` but as a newline. But how do we write a backslash then? We need to escape it, too, resulting in `\\` for a single backslash and `\\n` for the output `\n`.

[Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), also [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

Alternatively you can use "raw" strings, i.e. prefixing your strings with an **r**, to disable interpreting escape sequences is your strings:

```py
Sys.stdout.write(r"abc\ndef")
```

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to escaping the backslash, you can disable backslash-escaping entirely by using a raw string literal:

```
>>> print(r"abc\ndef")
abc\ndef
```

Comment: You still need to backslash-escape a backslash if it's the last character, e.g. `r'test\\'`.